# How do I add a resolution on Lubuntu 13.04?

Tags: resolution, lubuntu

Current resolution is 1920x1080. 
I would like to adjust to 1600x900 resolution, but it is not an option in the Display Settings.

How can I set my resolution to 1600x900?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [LXDE](http://www.sudo-juice.com/change-lxde-screen-resolution-ubuntu-lubuntu/) to change resolution of lubuntu,

Steps to be followed :

1)open up the terminal

2)Open up your default text editor hear considering leafpad from terminal

> sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE/autostart

3)Sample command would be like this

> xrandr --auto --output DVI-1 --primary --mode 1680x1050 --left-of
>   DVI-0

The commands explanation is as follows :

> –auto : enables connected devices in their preferred mode
>
> –output DVI-1 : selects the output device to modify
>
> –primary : specifies the selected device as primary
>
> –mode : sets a specific mode for the output device
>
> –left-of DVI-0 : sets position of the devide to “left of” another
>   device (DVI-0)

write a autostart file like this :

Now add your commands to the bottom of the file adding a @ before the actual command

```
@xscreensaver -no-splash
@lxpanel --profile LXDE
@pcmanfm --desktop --profile LXDE
@/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
@xrandr --auto --output DVI-1 --primary --mode 1600x900 --left-of DVI-0
```

Reboot your computer to make changes effect.

For additional reference you could refer [here](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xorg/2007-August/027490.html)

Comment: Took me forever to figure this out. I had to use eDP1 in the places where you put DVI-1. DVI-1 is not a thing on my laptop.